# How to solve the Error: Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type for generic c# interface?

Tags: c#

On writting this code into my project i am getting the error that

> Error  1   Inconsistent accessibility: field type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<Jain_milan.Childrendata>'` is less accessible than field `'Jain_milan.addchild.m_children'`
>      Error  2   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<Jain_milan.Childrendata>'` is less accessible than method `'Jain_milan.addchild.addchild(System.Collections.Generic.List<Jain_milan.Childrendata>)'`

```
namespace Jain_milan
{
        public partial class addchild : Form
        {
            List<Label> label = new List<Label>();
            List<TextBox> textbox = new List<TextBox>();
            List<ComboBox> combobox = new List<ComboBox>();
            List<DateTimePicker> datetimepicker = new List<DateTimePicker>();
            public List<Childrendata> m_children = new List<Childrendata>();
            public addchild(List<Childrendata> children)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.m_children = children; //Initialize the same List as sent by Mainform
            }
```

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand?

Comment: Double check the access modifiers on the classes you're using.

Comment: It's saying that a public item is using a private type. Make sure the access modifiers are consistent

Comment: @VJain: Were you able to understand and solve this issue?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Without posting your entire relevant code i'll try a hunch:

the class **Childrendata** is declared as not-public and (as we can see) the variable **m_children** is public

Threfore a public variable cannot expose a less accessible type, in this case, **Childrendata**

Additionally, what you might want is to turn **m_children** private as well as this is usually the best practice

Comment: It's clearer once the quoted errors are cleaned up, since the original question was swallowing the `<>` angled brackets.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that the `Childrendata` class is `private` (or `internal`, or implicitly `internal` by not specifying a visibility modifier)

Since `List<Childrendata> m_children` is public, `Childrendata` needs to be public as well.

Change `Childrendata` to `public` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

`Childrendata` isn't public. How, then, do you expect someone calling `addchild` to be able to provide the required parameter?

The obvious fixes are to change the accessibility of `addchild` or `Childrendata`.

Answer (score 1):

just make the method `addChilde(List<object> childeren)` or only object not list
then do this

```
var Listchild = childeren as List<childe>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use access modifier two times. if you used public class than you should not use the instance public. public partial class Record : ContentPage { List datas = new List() { I used record class public but not list.

Comment: Could you clarify what solution to the question do you propose in your answer as currently it's not very clear?

Comment: Are you using public class?

Comment: if you using the class public then don't use your instance public, just create your instance/object without access modifier. if you want to create your object or instance public then you must be create your class private or without access modifier.